# FontAwesome 5 SVG as square element

Tags: html, css, svg, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I am trying to use a font awesome 5 svg as a background image. However, it isn't showing up, and I don't know how to change the color. This is what I am using:

```
.no-profile-image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  background: url('/images/fa-solid.svg#user');
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

I can use it as an html svg element, but then I can't make the item square like I did as a background image above. I have tried the following but it makes element the oval shaped:

```
svg.no-profile-image {
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
}

<svg class="no-profile-image">
    <use xlink:href="/images/fa-solid.svg#user" fill="white"></use>
</svg>
```

How can I either make this a background image so my div is square or make it a square html svg element?

Comment: Have you tried to use it as `<i>`? Because even if you use it as icon, it still converts it as `SVG` and just comments out the `<i>` tag. The library is doing that `all.js`.

Comment: I have tried both `i.no-profile-image` and `i.fa.fa-user` the first one gives me no image, and the second one displays as if I wrote the html inline.

Comment: `<i class="fas fa-user"></i>` try like that. "fas" means "font awesome solid".

Comment: strange... It started working... It is square now...

Comment: Did you put the `all.js` in the `<head>` ?

Comment: Maybe that is the difference... I might have just been using `all.css` instead of `all.js` (yesterday) when I was trying before...

Comment: I'll write an answer explaining how to use the new font awesome 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get Font Awesome 5 working, you must first include the `JavaScript` library in the `<head>` like this:

```
<head>
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.1/js/all.js"></script>
</head>
```

Then, in order to get the icon (the user icon in this example) you must type the following:

```
<i class="fas fa-user"></i>
```

`fas` stands for "font awesome solid".

There are 4 types of icons now. `Solid`, `Regular`, `Light` and `Brands`.

You can now even change the size of the icon within the `<i>` class by typing `fa-lg` for example. Read more about it here: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/svg-with-js

Comment: I think is `Regular`, not retro